# GCS .csv in DataFlow job through a google cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am following [this](https://medium.com/@aishwarya.gupta3/cloud-function-to-start-a-data-flow-job-on-a-new-file-upload-in-google-cloud-storage-using-trigger-30270b31a06d) guide to create to a google cloud function that starts up a DataFlow job during a GCS bucket trigger.  My questions is around the template and the inout file. I would have this portion in my dataflow pipeline to get the source data (GCS csv)through a `TextIO.read`, but I am unsure how format this part of the pipeline to take into account a file from a bucket trigger. Would I have something like `"ReadTable" >> TextIO.read().metadata`?

```
p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
raw_values = (
            p 
            | "ReadTable" >> TextIO.read().from("gs://bucket/file.csv")
            | "custFunc" >> beam.Map(CallAPI)
            | "writeTable" >> WriteToBigQuery('newtablw', project='project1', 
                                               dataset='test', schema=table_schema,
                                               write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
                                               create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a Dataflow template, you can [create runtime parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/creating-templates#using-runtime-parameters-in-your-pipeline-code) that you provide when you run the template.

Define the template that you want, for instance, file_in and file_out. Then, when your Cloud Functions is trigger by a GCS event, you can get the [event data to extract the bucket and the file name](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#sample_function_code), concatenate them and provide them as file_in dataflow parameter.